# ADOBE AEM/CQ sightly string operations

Tags: aem, sightly

I need to do some string operations in sightly, like checking if the string is starting with '/content' and if yes append '.html' at the end. Is this possible in sightly ?

Answer (score 2):

Sightly was designed specifically to avoid having such logic in sightly templates. What you need to do is, you need to create a Sling Model for your component that is going to perform the logic you want and expose the result from there.

On a side note, in your particular use case, you might want to take a closer look at AEM's link checker.

Answer (score 1):

You could however do something like this:

```
<a href="${properties.path ? properties.path : 'contact'}.html">${properties.link ? properties.link : 'Get in Touch'}</a>
```